# How do "Fixed-length records" and "Fixed-length fields" increases database performance?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, external-tables

Could anyone please explain the below two statements w.r.t the Oracle external table performance improvement with the `ORACLE_LOADER` access driver:

1. Fixed-length records are processed faster than records terminated by
   a string.
2. Fixed-length fields are processed faster than delimited fields.

Explanation with code might help me to understand the concept in depth. here is the two syntax(s):

***Fixed field length***

```
create table ext_table_fixed (
   field_1 char(4),
   field_2 char(30)
)
organization external (
   type       oracle_loader
   default directory ext_dir
   access parameters (
     records delimited by newline
     fields (
       field_1 position(1: 4) char( 4),
       field_2 position(5:30) char(30)
    )
  )
  location ('file')
)
reject limit unlimited;
```

***Comma delimited***

```
create table ext_table_csv (
  i   Number,
  n   Varchar2(20),
  m   Varchar2(20)
)
organization external (
  type              oracle_loader
  default directory ext_dir
  access parameters (
    records delimited  by newline
    fields  terminated by ','
    missing field values are null
  )
  location ('file.csv')
)
reject limit unlimited;
```

Comment: It would help if you included where you read this.

Comment: In what language would you like to read the code explaining your question?

Comment: @TildalWave In oracle terminology obviously

Comment: I suspect you are referring to the (specific to Oracle) feature of **[external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96652/ch11.htm)** but it's not at all clear from the question.

Comment: whoever down-voted please clarify here! What the question lagging due to that down-vote i have been given. This is Q/A forum. So i posted here. Do you think that this question doesn't have anything technicality to know?

Comment: @CodeLover - I'm asking because PL/SQL is quite similar to Pascal. I'm not as good using PL/SQL as Pascal, though. Cheers!

Comment: Conceptually, @Matt Ball answered your question pretty good below, I'm giving that a +1, I don't know who gave you a -1 to your question, but maybe if you edit it to be a bit more specific, we can up-vote it? So far it reads more like it would belong in the [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com). ;)

Comment: You can find a bit more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_params.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm#i1006569), @Matt Ball's explanation still stands though ;)

Comment: @TildalWave any guess why now down-vote? Really some people here totally crazy. If they didn't get the depth of any question,put down-vote. Very worst it is.

Comment: re: downvotes http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54914/133242

Comment: I have seen many more posts here in `SO` which has been closed by some people - who are crazy and ugly, and later that question got 99 votes and 6-7 useful questions. Voting up or down is totally a human's mind chemistry,if it works then Ok or if not then down-vote. I believe.

Comment: Can anyone help me to explain how these two `create table` defination would impact on performance?

Comment: @CodeLover - no idea really, but you shouldn't be too sensitive to down-votes here, or indeed anywhere else. You asked your question and you got a response, that's all that matters. The added content to your question is just as well answered by @Matt Ball. The `create table` function itself wouldn't be any slower either case, but accessing records in a `comma delimited` `variable length` table would, as opposed to when `fixed field length` is used. It's all about identifying record position and its data length when retrieving its data. Again, see @Matt Ball answer for explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplified, conceptual, non-database-specific explanation:

When the maximum possible record length is known in advance, the end of the record/the beginning of the next record can be found in constant time. This is because that location is computable using simple addition, very much analogous to array indexing. Imagine that I'm using `int`s as pointers to records, and that the record size is an integer constant defined somewhere. Then, to get from the current record location to the next:

```
int current_record = /* whatever */;
int next_record = current_record + FIXED_RECORD_SIZE;
```

That's it!

Alternatively, when using string-terminated (or otherwise delimited) records and fields, you could imagine that the next field/record is found by a linear-time scan, which has to look at every character until the delimiter is found. As before,

```
char DELIMITER = ','; // or whatever
int current_record = /* whatever */;
int next_record = current_record;
while(character_at_location(next_record) != DELIMITER) {
    next_record++;
}
```

This might be a simplified or naïve version of the real-world implementation, but the general idea still stands: you can't easily do the same operation in constant time, and even if it were constant time, it's unlikely to be as fast as performing a single add operation.

Comment: could you explain this with code and diagram,which might help us to take the concept quickly?

Comment: Does my 2nd question's answer same as the first one,as in your above post?

Comment: Yes. Fields vs records, it's all pretty much the same at the conceptual level that my answer covers.

Comment: Scroll to the _trim_spec_ section in [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_params.htm). It also changes data type assumption with CHAR(1) for a nondelimited field, and CHAR(255) for a delimited field (->from that [same document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_params.htm)).

Comment: @TildalWave direct link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_params.htm#sthref1743

Comment: The classic Joel article, Back to Basics, applies here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Answer (score 0):

I checked this and in my case performance deteriorated! I have a 1GB csv file with integer values, each of them is 10 characters long with padding, fields separated by "," and records separated by "\n". I have to following script (I also tried to set the fixed record size and removed ltrim, but it didn't help).

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE ints_ext (id0 NUMBER(10),
  2                  id1 NUMBER(10),
  3                  id2 NUMBER(10),
  4                  id3 NUMBER(10),
  5                  id4 NUMBER(10),
  6                  id5 NUMBER(10),
  7                  id6 NUMBER(10),
  8                  id7 NUMBER(10),
  9                  id8 NUMBER(10),
 10                  id9 NUMBER(10))
 11  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
 12  TYPE oracle_loader
 13  DEFAULT DIRECTORY tpch_dir
 14  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
 15         RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
 16         BADFILE 'bad_%a_%p.bad'
 17         LOGFILE 'log_%a_%p.log'
 18         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 19         MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL)
 20  LOCATION ('data1_1.csv'))
 21  parallel 1
 22  REJECT LIMIT 0
 23  NOMONITORING;

SQL> select count(*) from ints_ext;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   9761289

Elapsed: 00:00:43.68
SQL> select /*+ parallel(1) tracing(STRIP,1) */ * from ints_ext;

no rows selected

Elapsed: 00:00:43.78

SQL> CREATE TABLE ints_ext (id0 NUMBER(10),
  2                  id1 NUMBER(10),
  3                  id2 NUMBER(10),
  4                  id3 NUMBER(10),
  5                  id4 NUMBER(10),
  6                  id5 NUMBER(10),
  7                  id6 NUMBER(10),
  8                  id7 NUMBER(10),
  9                  id8 NUMBER(10),
 10                  id9 NUMBER(10))
 11  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
 12  TYPE oracle_loader
 13  DEFAULT DIRECTORY tpch_dir
 14  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
 15         RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
 16         BADFILE 'bad_%a_%p.bad'
 17         LOGFILE 'log_%a_%p.log'
 18         FIELDS ltrim (
 19         id0 position(1:10) char(10),
 20         id1 position(12:21) char(10),
 21         id2 position(23:32) char(10),
 22         id3 position(34:43) char(10),
 23         id4 position(45:54) char(10),
 24         id5 position(56:65) char(10),
 25         id6 position(67:76) char(10),
 26         id7 position(78:87) char(10),
 27         id8 position(89:98) char(10),
 28         id9 position(100:109) char(10)
 29         ))
 30  LOCATION ('data1_1.csv'))
 31  parallel 1
 32  REJECT LIMIT 0
 33  NOMONITORING;

SQL> select count(*) from ints_ext;


  COUNT(*)
----------
   9761289

Elapsed: 00:00:50.38
SQL> 
select /*+ parallel(1) tracing(STRIP,1) */ * from ints_ext;

no rows selected

Elapsed: 00:00:45.26
```

Comment: also no improvement after changing the type number to char