# Can I create a fixed length type in oracle database?

Tags: oracle

Using Oracle 11gR2, I have a need to create a fixed length string comprised of 200 + fields from a table.

I have created a dynamic select statement that creates this by reading a table that has the relationship between the fixed length string and the database fields. I end up with something like;

```
select rpad(char_field1, 20,' ') ||
       lpad(num_field1,6,'0') ||
       rpad(' ',8,' ') AS FIXED_STRING
from my_table
```

It works fine, but is CPU intensive with all the concatenation and padding etc.

I noticed that there is the ability to create an external [table of type fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538386/how-do-fixed-length-records-and-fixed-length-fields-increases-database-perfo), but my data never needs to be written to disk, just passed to a program for processing.

I wondered if there was an equivalent in memory structure similar to;

```
TYPE MY_RECORD_TYPE IS RECORD
(
  CHAR_FIELD1 position(1:20) VARCHAR2(20),
  NUM_FIELD2 position(21:6) NUMBER(6),
  FILL_FIELD1 position(28,8) VARCHAR2(8)
);
```

That would allow me to create a string to pass to something else, in my case VB.NET?

My overall goal is to come up with the most efficient way of creating fixed length strings from column data in a table.

Answer (score 0):

[Virtual Columns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-schemamanagement-089869.html) might work for you - hard to tell from the information given.  On the table itself you define the virtual column - which will concatenate the fields you are interested in.

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE
 ADD (FIXED_STRING char(34) Generated Always as 
 (rpad(char_field1, 20,' ') ||  lpad(num_field1,6,'0') || rpad(' ',8,' ') ));
```

The virtual column can then be indexed, etc...

Comment: Brian a virtual column seems like it would have the same performance hit as the query I wrote, with the added benefit(?) of having the performance hit whenever a "select *" is executed. However thank you, as I was unfamiliar with "virtual column," and will investigate it further.